# (Any concept behind of forEach loop) Why forEach loop is not working for break

Tags: javascript, foreach

Is there anything I am missing about forEach loop
   this gives an error

> VM847:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at :2:9

And this is working fine for normal for loop.

```
var myArray = [{name:'John'}, {name:'Doe'}, {name:'Mice'}]
myArray.forEach(function(item, i){     
    if(item.name == 'Doe'){
      console.log(i);
      break;
    }
});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` is a method; not a loop statement.

Comment: Ohh I missed that forEach is a function and we have to use return for this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot break a forEach loop, if you want it to stop you would have to throw an exception